# Changing html input type tags to label which are created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

i am new to js and jquery.
**html**

```
<div id="answerdiv" name="answerdiv" class="answerdiv">
    <div id="answerweightdiv" class="answerweightdiv">
        <input id="answerweight" class="answerweight" type="number" name="answerweight" placeholder="Weight" maxlength="3" tabindex="7" onBlur="exchangeLabelsanswerweight(this);">
    </div>
</div>
```

the above field is created dynamically n number of times 1 below another
i am trying to create a js function that only converts the current active element to label and not others

**js**

```
function exchangeLabelsanswerweight(element)
{
    var result = $(element).val();
    if(result!="")
    {
        $(element).remove();
        $("#answerweightdiv").append("<label id='answertext' onClick='exchangeFieldanswerweight(this);'>"+result+"</label>");
    }
}
function exchangeFieldanswerweight(element)
{
    var result = element.innerHTML; 
    $(element).remove();
    $("#answerweightdiv").append("<input id='answerweight' class='answerweight' value="+result+" type='number' name='answerweight' placeholder='Weight' maxlength='3' tabindex='7' onBlur='exchangeLabelsanswerweight(this);'>");
}
```

Comment: *"the above field is created dynamically n number of times 1 below another"* But with different `id` values, right? Because `id` values **must** be unique on the page.

Comment: What is the trigger that creates them dynamically ? is there an Add button that fires a JS function that adds the field to the DOM ?

Comment: ids are not given uniquely. all the js work is done by classname only till now

Comment: If you're not using the ids anyway, then leave them out.